# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ' when importing pickled file with custom class

Tags: python, pickle, modulenotfounderror

I have a project directory that looks like this:

```
maindir/
   main.py
   __init__.py
   submoduledir/
        __init__.py
        main2.py
        classdb.py
```

Now I save a custom class in the main2.py called MyClass.

if I save an object of class MyClass with pickle while executing main2.py, I can load the same file when executing main2.py but not when executing main.py

Viceversa, if I save the same custom class in the main2.py while executing main.py, this can be loaded only when executing main.py and not main2.py

I get the error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '.......`

Is there a way to have it working both ways?

**EDIT with example:**
It is a bit more complicated then what I explained but here it is:
you need to run first main2.py to generate the file and then main.py to load the file, it will give you the module not found error

main.py:

```
import pickle
from submoduledir import classdb


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('submoduledir/file_save_by_submodule.pkl', 'rb') as handle:
        a = pickle.load(handle)
```

main2.py:

```
import pickle
from classdb import MyClass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myclass = MyClass()
    w = myclass.test_myclass2()
    with open('file_save_by_submodule.pkl', 'wb') as handle:
        pickle.dump(w, handle)
    print('ciao')
```

classdb.py:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def test_myclass2(self):
        return MyClass2()


class MyClass2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'a'
```

Many thanks

Comment: Could you share some code snippets? Or better yet, a reproducible example?

Comment: can you show us your code of how you are importing the file by?